# Dependency Property to Dependency Property Binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I want to bind two Dependency Property, both in one instance of object or different instance of object or different type of instance of object.

So, i read the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-create-a-binding-in-code?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

But i see the method is:

Set source:

- set Path string which is a name of instance property with user defined type
- set that source instance of object which contain that property which have that name

Set destination:

- set destination instance of destination dependency property
- set real static dependency property

So, my question is: Is exists any method to set two Dependency Property bind look like this:

```
SetBindingMethod(sourceInstanceOfObject, sourceDependencyProperty, destinationInstanceOfObject, destinationDependencyProperty)
```

Here is my test code is working, but not that what i want:

```
class TestClass : DependencyObject
{
    public int Int0
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(Int0Property); }
        set { SetValue(Int0Property, value); }
    }

    public int Int1
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(Int1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Int1Property, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Int0Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Int0), typeof(int), typeof(TestClass), new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(Int0Changed)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Int1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Int1), typeof(int), typeof(TestClass), new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(Int1Changed)));

    private static void Int0Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Int0 changed: " + e.NewValue);
    }

    private static void Int1Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Int1 changed: " + e.NewValue);
    }

    internal void Test()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Int0 += 1;
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Int1 -= 1;
        }
    }

    public TestClass()
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding(nameof(Int0));
        binding.Source = this;
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, Int1Property, binding);
    }
}
```

I hope that is clear, i'm on my limit of my english features :)

br: ExtSol

Comment: Since these are public properties, it is not safe to set bindings for them.
Bindings can be changed from outside.
Therefore, the only option (and the best one) is to track property changes in callback methods.
You have implemented it.
And it is not clear why you are not satisfied with such an implementation.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but be aware that `DependecyObject` is a View-layer component and should not be used in the ViewModel-layer. In the ViewModel-layer you use POCO properties and `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: You can always bind a dependency property (Binding.Target) to anything else, also another dependency property. The only constraint is that the target must be a dependency property. To set the source: you can set the source directly (Binding.Source) if you have a reference to the instance or use tree traversal (Binding.RelativeSource) to look it up or create a reference using the name of the source element (Binding.ElementName). It is not clear what your actual problem is. [Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0).

Comment: "*my test code is working, but not that what i want*" - what else do you want than working code? Please clarify your problem.